# SQLException: Before start of result set

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, prepared-statement

I've checked this issue in other posts and it said that to point on the first line in the table I need to perform "result.next()" .
But still I get this problem, I checked the input of the function, it's ok and matches the info in the database.
it doesn't perform the "while" loop, like the content of the table is empty...
I'm using GWT so the debugging is painful !

The table : picId(primary_key), book, fromChapter, toChapter ....(the important ones)

content: book = 1 , chapter = 6.
and the database contains such a row.
I hope i'm not missing something stupid over here as usual ! :)

```
public List<PicAsset> getPicture(int book, int chapter) throws Exception

  {

    System.out.print("getPicture ok " + book +"," + chapter);
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    List<PicAsset> relevantAssets = new ArrayList<PicAsset>();
    PicAsset relAsset;


    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM picasset WHERE book = ? AND fromChapter = ?");

        //System.out.print("connection" + conn);
        pstmt.setInt(1, book);
        pstmt.setInt(2, chapter);
       // pstmt.setInt(3, chapter);
       // pstmt.setInt(4, chapter);
        result = pstmt.executeQuery();


        while (result.next()) {

            System.out.print(result.next());
            relAsset = new PicAsset(result.getInt("picId"),result.getInt("book"), result.getInt("fromChapter"), result.getInt("toChapter"),result.getInt("fromVerse"),result.getInt("toVerse"),result.getString("creator"),result.getString("discription"),result.getString("source"),result.getString("title"),result.getString("duration"),result.getString("url"));
            relevantAssets.add(relAsset);

        }
    }

        catch (SQLException sqle) 
        {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally
        {
            // Cleanup
            result.close();
            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }

    return relevantAssets;


    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
getPicture ok 1,6connectioncom.mysql.jdbc.Connection@18e476fajava.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkRowPos(ResultSet.java:700)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getNativeString(ResultSet.java:3747)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getStringInternal(ResultSet.java:4979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:4810)
    at com.biblereader.server.MySQLConnection.getPicture(MySQLConnection.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace

Comment: Never used the stack trace I'm reading about how it can help me find the bug

Comment: @MarounSassine Is `discription` really spelled as it is in the database?

Comment: yes it's spelled wrong also there  'discription'. where should I look in the stack trace to track what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem would seem to be here;

```
while (result.next()) {

    System.out.print(result.next());

    ...
```

The first call to `result.next()` in the while loop advances the cursor to the first result. The second one in the print advances it to the second result (which may not exist).

If there is only one result from the query, the cursor is invalid after the second call to next(), and getting data from the cursor in the next line will fail.

Comment: no I don't think so, because if I replace " System.out.print(result.next()); " with System.out.print("I'm in the while"); it's never printed in console... So the result.next() is always null for some reason

Comment: @MarounSassine Depending on platform, you may want to use `println` instead of `print`, or buffering may cause the output to not show. The crash is inside `getString`, and I can't see that being reached without a result being present.

Comment: console : " getPicture ok 1,6in whileStarting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.biblereader.shared.PicAsset' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.biblereader.shared.PicAsset@301cc071"  

I've added a default constructor to PicAsset class and it worked... an issue withe "IsSerializable"... I don't know why it works now